# Is there a way to dynamically print all the fields and their values in a c types structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, struct, ctypes

```
import ctypes as c

class list (c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', c.c_uint16),
                ('y', c.c_uint16 * 2)]

class data (c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('a', c.c_float),
                ('b', c.c_float),
                ('c', c.c_float)]

class parameters (c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('variable1', c.c_uint16),
                ('variable2', c.c_uint16),
                ('tablelist', list),
                ('datalist', data * 2)]

a = b'\x05\x00\x14\x00\x1E\x00\x0A\x00\x0F\x00\x14\x00\x00\x40\xFA\x43\x66\x26\x16\x44\x33\x33\x48\x44\x66\x26\x96\x43\x33\x33\xC8\x43\x00\x20\xFA\x43'

instance = parameters.from_buffer_copy(a)

print (instance)

print ('---------------------------')

for fields in instance._fields_:
    print (fields[0], getattr(instance, fields[0]))

print ('---------------------------')

for fields in instance.tablelist._fields_:
    print (fields[0], getattr(instance.tablelist, fields[0]))

print ('---------------------------')

for fields in instance.tablelist.y:
    print (instance.tablelist._fields_[1][0], fields)

print ('---------------------------')

for x in instance.datalist:
    print(x)
    for fields in x._fields_:
        print(fields[0], getattr(x, fields[0]))
```

Output:

```
<__main__.parameters object at 0x00000267B1615DC0>
---------------------------
variable1 5
variable2 20
tablelist <__main__.list object at 0x00000267B17848C0>       
datalist <__main__.data_Array_2 object at 0x00000267B17848C0>
---------------------------
x 30
y <__main__.c_ushort_Array_2 object at 0x00000267B1784DC0>   
---------------------------
y 10
y 15
---------------------------
<__main__.data object at 0x00000267B1784DC0>
a 500.5
b 600.5999755859375
c 800.7999877929688
<__main__.data object at 0x00000267B1784E40>
a 300.29998779296875
b 400.3999938964844
c 500.25
```

I want to be able to print all fields of the structure and nested structures with just one loop, if it's possible. Instead of having four for loops to print all the fields of this structure, is it possible to do it with just one for loop? It'd be more efficient to write and read these to and from a csv file if there was a simpler way of accessing all the values.

Comment: Did you try checking whether the field has a type that needs to be inspected further, and using recursion? (If you were having trouble searching for this, it might be because the word "dynamically" doesn't accurately describe what you appear to want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below illustrates both a recursive helper function (`dump`, complicated) and simply defining a representation method (`__repr__`) for each class so it knows how to print itself which is a more object-oriented approach:

```py
import ctypes as c

def dump(obj, parent=None):
    if not hasattr(obj, '_fields_'):
        print(obj)
        return
    for att, typ in obj._fields_:
        subobj = getattr(obj, att)
        objname = obj.__class__.__name__
        name = objname if parent is None else parent + '.' + objname
        if hasattr(subobj, '_fields_'):
            dump(subobj, objname)
        elif issubclass(typ, c.Array):
            print(f'{name}.{att} =')
            for i, o in enumerate(subobj):
                print(f'[{i}]')
                dump(o, f'{name}.{att}')
        else:
            print(f'{name}.{att} = {subobj!r}')

class List(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', c.c_uint16),
                ('y', c.c_uint16 * 2)]
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'List(x={self.x}, y={list(self.y)})'

class Data(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('a', c.c_float),
                ('b', c.c_float),
                ('c', c.c_float)]
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Data(a={self.a}, b={self.b}, c={self.c})'

class Parameters(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('variable1', c.c_uint16),
                ('variable2', c.c_uint16),
                ('tablelist', List),
                ('datalist', Data * 2)]
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Parameters(v1={self.variable1}, v2={self.variable2}, tl={self.tablelist}, dl={list(self.datalist)})'

a = b'\x05\x00\x14\x00\x1E\x00\x0A\x00\x0F\x00\x14\x00\x00\x40\xFA\x43\x66\x26\x16\x44\x33\x33\x48\x44\x66\x26\x96\x43\x33\x33\xC8\x43\x00\x20\xFA\x43'

instance = Parameters.from_buffer_copy(a)
print(instance) # Uses __repr__ methods
print()
dump(instance)
```

Output:

```
Parameters(v1=5, v2=20, tl=List(x=30, y=[10, 15]), dl=[Data(a=500.5, b=600.5999755859375, c=800.7999877929688), Data(a=300.29998779296875, b=400.3999938964844, c=500.25)])

Parameters.variable1 = 5
Parameters.variable2 = 20
Parameters.List.x = 30
Parameters.List.y =
[0]
10
[1]
15
Parameters.datalist =
[0]
Parameters.datalist.Data.a = 500.5
Parameters.datalist.Data.b = 600.5999755859375
Parameters.datalist.Data.c = 800.7999877929688
[1]
Parameters.datalist.Data.a = 300.29998779296875
Parameters.datalist.Data.b = 400.3999938964844
Parameters.datalist.Data.c = 500.25
```